# Foreign Key Not Setting On CSV Upload -- Django

Tags: python, django, csv

When importing csv to django the foreign keys are not setting. May code may be wrong. I am able to import the foreign keys but I am not able set them in the product object.

I do not want to have to back through and set the foreignkeys manually.

models

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.category_name)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    #def get_absolute_url(self):
        #return reverse('products:category', args=[self.id]) #kwargs={'slug': self.slug}

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name

class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    company_url = models.URLField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=500)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.company_name)
        super(Company, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    #def get_absolute_url(self):
        #return reverse('products:category', args=[self.id]) #kwargs={'slug': self.slug}

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name

class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    manufacturer_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=500)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.manufacturer_name)
        super(Manufacturer, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    #def get_absolute_url(self):
        #return reverse('products:category', args=[self.id]) #kwargs={'slug': self.slug}

    def __str__(self):
        return self.manufacturer_name

class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    product_description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True, null=True)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer)
    buy_link = models.URLField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    product_image_url = models.URLField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    orginal_price = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    stock = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=500, unique=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify("{obj.product_name}-{obj.id}".format(obj=self))
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('products:product_detail', args=[self.slug]) #kwargs={'slug': self.slug}

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

views

```
def upload(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("home")

    csv_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    try:
        with open(csv_path + '/product.csv') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                _, created = Product.objects.get_or_create(
                    product_name=str(row[0]),
                    buy_link=str(row[2]),
                    product_image_url=str(row[3]),
                    price=str(row[4]),
                    orginal_price=str(row[5]),
                    product_description=str(row[6]),
                    stock=str(row[7]),
                    sku=str(row[10]),
                )
                _, created = Company.objects.get_or_create(
                    company_name=str(row[1]),
                )

                _, created = Manufacturer.objects.get_or_create(
                    manufacturer_name=str(row[8]),
                )

                _, created = Category.objects.get_or_create(
                    category_name=str(row[9]),
                )
        success = "Added to database"
        context = {"success": success}

    except csv.Error as e:
        print(e)
        context = {'error': e}

    template = "products/add.html"

    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: The way I'm thinking about it is if a company gets created you should insert the primary key of that company into the product table. So wouldn't you need to do the `.get_or_create()` of the company before the `.get_or_create()` of the product?

Comment: I am going to give that a try. Did not think of that way

Comment: Gave it a try did not work. Thanks

Comment: That's one less way to do it!

Comment: How about save(commit=False). I am not exactly sure how I should write it though

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure about `save(commit=False)`. It would seem that you'd want the commit to be `True`. Below I added a fleshed-out example of what it seems like needs to be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is an example of what I was thinking you'd need to do:

```
def upload(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("home")

    csv_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    try:
        with open(csv_path + '/product.csv') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                category_obj, created = Category.objects.get_or_create(
                    category_name=str(row[9]),
                )

                company_obj, created = Company.objects.get_or_create(
                    company_name=str(row[1]),
                )

                manufacturer_obj, created = Manufacturer.objects.get_or_create(
                    manufacturer_name=str(row[8]),
                )

                product_obj, created = Product.objects.get_or_create(
                    product_name=str(row[0]),
                    company=company_obj,
                    category=category_obj,
                    manufacturer=manufacturer_obj,
                    buy_link=str(row[2]),
                    product_image_url=str(row[3]),
                    price=str(row[4]),
                    orginal_price=str(row[5]),
                    product_description=str(row[6]),
                    stock=str(row[7]),
                    sku=str(row[10]),
                )

        success = "Added to database"
        context = {"success": success}

    except csv.Error as e:
        print(e)
        context = {'error': e}

    template = "products/add.html"

    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: I followed your code now I am getting a invalid literal for int() with base 10: '123 REFILLS' which would be on the company field.

Comment: Ah I forgot that Django has an automatic `id` field. That makes sense. I've updated the code.

Comment: Damn thought that was it but I got this now: Cannot assign "1": "Product.company" must be a "Company" instance.